# How can I read resources file from outside project directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

Below code works fine if file location is resources folder but when file location is outside the project directory like(c:\file.json) it fails.
How can we load file from outside project directory.

```
    @Bean
    public UserInfo readFile() {
        String fileName="prop.json";
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
        try {
             UserInfo info= new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()).readValue(file, UserInfo.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use getResource() then. This is used for resources that are embedded into the jar – ask yourself if this file will be contained in the jar. For file outside the jar (in the file system), just pass the string  path to the File

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Configuration class that implements **WebMvcConfigurer** and
override the **addResourceHadndler** Method to add new resource to spring context.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public  void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        
        // register you resource here
    }
    
}
```